# Why is R giving me the error "dims [product 28550] do not match the length of object [1]"

Tags: r, dataframe

I am new in R so bear with me.
I have a dataframe (df) of 1 column with 28550 observations. Basically, this is an observation over time with 0.02 second time resolution. I would like to change the dimensions in order to have a dataframe of 50 rows and 571 columns. This would be one column per second. I check whether it has the dim attribute, which it does as below.

```
>dim(df) 
[1] 28545     1
```

While changing the dimensions of the dataframe as follows:

```
>df1 <- dim(df) <- c(50, 571)

#I get the following error:

Error in dim(df) <- c(50, 571) : 
  dims [product 28550] do not match the length of object [1]
```

I cannot seem to find a reason for why this happens. Is it that it is the wrong type of data, i.e. integer? The number of observations fill 571 columns, so I do not understand the meaning of "do not match the length of object".

I have also tried:

```
matrix(unlist(t(df)), byrow=T, 50, 571)

#I get the following error:

In matrix(unlist(t(df)), byrow = T, 50, 571) :
  data length [28545] is not a sub-multiple or multiple of the number of rows [50]
```

Is there then another way to do this?

Appreciate the help.

Comment: The product doesn't match `50 * 571` `28545`.  I think you may neeed to `pad` some `NA` at the end i.e. `length<-`(unlist(df), 28550)`

Comment: Yeah `50*571=28550`, not `28545`. You can't just make 5 more values appear without being more clear how you want that to happen.

Comment: Excuse the mistake, The dataframe has 28545 observations. This is however variable for every data file that I will use the script for. It turns out that changing the category of the value to "number" in excel solved the issue. That means that the type of data, i.e. integer, may have been the problem? However, adding NA did not really help. I tried even adding some numbers at the end to match the number of observations. Did not help.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to `unlist`, pad `NA` at the end with `length<-` and then convert to `matrix`

```
matrix(`length<-`(unlist(df), 50 * 571), 50, 571)
```

i.e. with a reproducible example

```
matrix(`length<-`(1:7, 10), 5, 2)
```